# WP-Members plugin add class to label/input

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

According to [this guide](http://rocketgeek.com/plugins/wp-members/users-guide/filter-hooks/wpmem_register_form_rows/) I can add classes to inputs or labels, however I'm unsure how to get it work. The example make me feel like the code below should work, but clearly it's wrong.

```
add_filter( 'wpmem_register_form_rows', 'my_register_form_rows_filter', 10, 2 );

function my_register_form_rows_filter( $rows, $toggle )
{
    zip => array (
        'field_before' => '<div class="div_text new_class">'
         )

return $rows;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not wrong the 'field_before' add a wrapper to the input, so you need to use insted

```
 'field' => '<input name="option_name" type="text" id="option_name" value="" class="YOURCLASS" />'
```

**EDIT:**

you need to close your div

```
'field_before' => '<div class="div_text">'
'field_after' => '</div>'
```

Comment: I'm trying to add a class the div that surrounds the input.

Answer (score 0):

The question and the previous answer are close, but not correct.  The correct way to use the wpmem_register_form_rows in this way would as follows:

```
add_filter( 'wpmem_register_form_rows', 'my_register_form_rows_filter', 10, 2 );
function my_register_form_rows_filter( $rows, $toggle ) {
    $rows['zip']['field_before'] = '<div class="div_text new_class">';
    return $rows;
}
```

Addressing the previous answer about closing the div, you actually don't have to.  The closing div will already be there - all you are doing here is changing, not adding, the wrapper for a specific field (the "zip" field, in this case).